# Custom Classloader not working well

Tags: java, classloader

I want to write my own custom class loader to do something before loading classes. The following code can work well if the main class which I want to invoke is simple. For example, if the invoked main method only print some messages, then it work fine without error. However, if it invokes some complicated main method, for example, the main method in 'com.iisi.rest.Start' will create a http server using jersey like below, then it failed.

```
HttpServer server =   
HttpServerFactory.create("http://127.0.0.1:10987/rest");
server.start();
```

It's not the problem of those classes I want to load, because if I comment out the code like below and let the findSystemClass() method to load classes, all will work well.

```
claz = defineClass(name, classData, 0, classData.length);
```

I've been searched the answer for a long time, and still can't figure out...

```
public class MyClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClassLoader myLoader = new MyClassLoader();
        Class claz;
        String realArgs[] = new String[0];
        try {
            claz = myLoader.loadClass("com.iisi.rest.Start", true);
            // claz = myLoader.loadClass("com.iisi.practice.Test", true);
            Class[] mainArgs = { (new String[1]).getClass() };
            Method main = claz.getMethod("main", mainArgs);
            Object[] argsArray = { realArgs };
            main.invoke(null, argsArray);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
    public Class<?> loadClass(String name, boolean resolve)
            throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class claz = null;
        claz = findLoadedClass(name);
        if (claz != null) {
            return claz;
        }
        try {
            byte[] classData = readFile(name);
            if (classData != null) {
                claz = defineClass(name, classData, 0, classData.length);
                if (claz != null) {
                    System.out.println(name + " is loaded by MyClassLoader");
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassFormatError e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        if (claz == null) {
            claz = findSystemClass(name);
            if (claz != null) {
                System.out.println(name + " is loaded by system class loader");
            }
        }
        // check
        if (claz == null) {
            System.out.println(name + " failed");
        }
        if (resolve && claz != null) {
            resolveClass(claz);
        }
        return claz;
    }
}
```

Below is my partial error messages...

```
com.sun.jersey.localization.Localizable is loaded by MyClassLoader
com.sun.jersey.localization.Localizer is loaded by MyClassLoader
java.util.MissingResourceException is loaded by system class loader
java.util.Locale is loaded by system class loader
com.sun.jersey.localization.LocalizableMessage is loaded by MyClassLoader
java.util.ResourceBundle is loaded by system class loader
java.text.MessageFormat is loaded by system class loader
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.iisi.formal.MyClassLoader.main(MyClassLoader.java:56)
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.WebApplicationProvider: The class com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.WebApplicationProviderImpl implementing provider interface com.sun.jersey.spi.container.WebApplicationProvider could not be instantiated: Cannot cast com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.WebApplicationProviderImpl to com.sun.jersey.spi.container.WebApplicationProvider
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceFinder.fail(ServiceFinder.java:602)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceFinder.access$800(ServiceFinder.java:159)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceFinder$LazyObjectIterator.hasNext(ServiceFinder.java:892)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.WebApplicationFactory.createWebApplication(WebApplicationFactory.java:64)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:160)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:264)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:246)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.httpserver.HttpServerFactory.create(HttpServerFactory.java:117)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.httpserver.HttpServerFactory.create(HttpServerFactory.java:92)
    at com.iisi.rest.Start.main(Start.java:47)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.WebApplicationProviderImpl to com.sun.jersey.spi.container.WebApplicationProvider
    at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3176)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceFinder$LazyObjectIterator.hasNext(ServiceFinder.java:851)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: Cannot cast com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.WebApplicationProviderImpl to com.sun.jersey.spi.container.WebApplicationProvider

Comment: As far as I could google it, it appears to be a problem with Jersey installation somehow connected with pom.xml.

Comment: @andy Can you show us how do you register resources with Jersey, and which version are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your answering. I use jersey-bundle:1.8 as my dependency. But I don't think it's the problem with jersey, because the source of those classes are form a executable jar which is running well, I unzip the jar and set as a classpath in my eclipse in order to do some test conveniently. Besides, if I use findSystemClass() to load classes, everything goes fine too. I really don't understand why...